# Event doesn't work when element isn't loaded directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table with many checkboxes which is generated with Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "jsonDevisUtilisateur.php?ra=" + $('#ra').val(),
    success: function(data) {
        var table = "<table class='dvs'><tr><td>Numéro</td><td>Client</td><td>Site</td><td>Libellé</td><td>Statut</td><td></td></tr>"
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            table += "<tr><td>" + data[i].numDevis + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + data[i].client + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + data[i].site + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + data[i].libelle + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + data[i].statut + "</td>";
            table += "<td><input type='checkbox' class='box' value='" + data[i].id + "' name='box[]'></td></tr>"
        }
        table += "</table>";
        document.getElementById('devis').innerHTML = table + "<br/><br/>";
    }
});
```

This part is working well !
The problem is when I'm trying to integrate a "select all" button.

My Javascript for it :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectall").on("change", function(e) {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

When my select all checkbox : `<input type='checkbox' id='selectall' name='selectall'>` is created on the same time than my HTML, it works.

But if I create my `<input type='checkbox' id='selectall' name='selectall'>` in my TABLE with my ajax function, it doesn't work, and nothing happens.

I'm pretty sure it is because the event is set to "selectall" at the load of the page but it doesn't exist yet and it doesn't look for it later.

What would be the solution ? Thanks for help

Comment: This might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: is selectall creating runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `event delegation` as follow:

```
$('#devis').on("change", "#selectall", function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your thinking :

If your selectall checkbox is created after the document ready code execution, jquery can't find it (as it's not created yet).

I won't recommand using the **live** function as it is deprecated and can be removed in futur version of jquery.

You can still use the **on** function but with a little modification :

```
$("#devis").on("change", "#selectall",function(e) {
```

Note that **#mycontainer** MUST exist on document load.

If you can't place a container, this will always work :

```
$("body").on("change", "#selectall",function(e) {
```